# SES: Delivery Status Notification (Failure)

Tags: email, mobile, amazon-ses

I use Amazon SES to delivery mail to mobile devide Japanese such as `****@docomo.ne.jp`, `******@softbank.ne.jp`. But I always get an error.

Example:

```
An error occurred while trying to deliver the mail to the following recipients:
******@docomo.ne.jp
Final-Recipient: rfc822; ******@docomo.ne.jp
Action: failed
Diagnostic-Code: smtp; 550 Unknown user ******@docomo.ne.jp
Status: 5.3.0
```

Comment: Ive had the same,not sure what to do.

Answer (score 8):

in my opinion, your mail domain is not supported in sending email through third party apps such as SES (or maybe some settings in your mail is blocking it).

i have tried to send mail from Yahoo and its not working. then i tried to send it via Gmail and send it to that Gmail account itself. it works like charm.

so my solution is: you better try another mail domain in this problem.

Comment: The same thing was happening to me.  Yahoo was giving me problems but Gmail wasn't, so I just used Gmail.

Comment: Thanks. Gmail works. Yahoo didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

> It turns out that a large percent of the bounced mail that SES
> forwards back isn't actually 100% readable by Gmail.

If this is your case, you can find the actual cause inside the *eml download file.

See more at  https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=324457

In my case was related to the suppression list for my  AWS account

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I verified the email & getting the issue as in the question.

I can able deliver the mail After I verified the domain.

I think No verification required for non-business domains like (Gmail, Outlook, etc..) & custom domain requires verification.

Answer (score 0):

Had issues with sending with @yahoo.com domain myself and this post helped me confirm my suspicions. Used a @gmail.com domain (with no custom profile settings) and it worked first try.